# What is the exact procedure for renewing a 'CN = dynamic' certificate on a Rancher UI console?

Tags: ssl, dynamic, browser, certificate, rancher

I installed the Rancher UI as a Docker container. In the web browser I see that the Rancher UI certificate 'dynamic' signed with 'dynamiclistener-ca' lasts only a year. I tried to use my certificate according to these instructions https://rancher.com/docs/rancher/v2.x/en/installation/other-installation-methods/single-node-docker/#option-c-bring-your-own -certificate-signed-by-a-recognized-ca (Option B), but the 'dynamic' certificate is displayed in the browser again after restarting the Rancher container. I also tried to modify the secret 'serving-cert' inside the Rancher K3s cluster 'local', but it didn't work out well because the Rancher UI lost its connection to the kubernetes cluster. Does anyone have experience with this problem?